# Force echo output to Browser before the PHP script loads

Tags: php

I want to output a "Please wait" message before a PHP script runs but it is output at the same time together with the other echo messages.

The purpose is to inform the user that the page is loading and that one is not tempted to think that the page is not loading.

MRE:

```
   
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: Mon, 24 Sep 2012 04:00:00 GMT");
    
    ob_start();
    echo "Please wait";
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
    sleep(1);
    
    run_a_function();
    
    function run_a_function() {
       // execute some php code, may take some time
       echo "progress..";
       // execute some php code, may take some time
       echo "progress..";
       // more..
    }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: @shingo: how does this help to answer my question? I'm already using flush();

Comment: I hope you have read the description of flush(), it says _"flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser."_ Whether you can flush or not depends on the web server.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no other way to output echo() immediately?

Comment: No good way, you can implement by iframe or javascript.

Comment: Where do I find examples ?